# Android meediaplayer play's next song automaticly?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play next song with `mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener()` but it only plays one next song and after that song ends mediaplayer stops.How to make mediaplayer play all the time?

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    mySongs = (ArrayList)b.getParcelableArrayList("songList");
    position = b.getInt("pos",0);
    u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
    mediaPlayer.start();

 mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position + 1).toString());
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wait until onCompletion. Just create both players at once and use [setNextMediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer(android.media.MediaPlayer)) to queue the second one

```
u1 = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
u2 = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position + 1).toString());
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u1);
mediaPlayerNext = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u2);
mediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mediaPlayerNext);
```

And you are not receiving `onCompletion` after the second song because you replace `mediaPlayer` value with a reference to a new player that doesn't have the listener set. Add `mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener()` to the onCompletion `handler`. You also don't need to prepare old player